# Export an ORACLE 11.2 table to a text file with iSQL

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, putty

I'm working with ORACLE 11.2 over a SSH connection (using Putty) my actual work tool is a Windows PC. ORACLE is installed on Ubuntu server and I'm very rusted on UNIX like systems, a lot of years since the last time I worked with them.

There is no installation of SQL*Plus so I cannot run the classic spool tool. So I need some guidance on what to do in order to accomplish what is been requested to me.

Comment: So what oracle client are you using, if not sqlplus?  Why not install it?

Comment: Right now I'm simply connecting over isql tool and running the queries I needed so far. Yes I would like to install it but here is where the guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I just asked my boss if it's possible to install del SQLPlues and he told we must simulate the client's architecture that's why SQLPlus wasn't installed from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resulted SqlPlus was indeed installed on the system but since it has been years since the last time I worked on UNIX like system I didn't know how to make the application work.

I first exported the bin path to my looged session:

```
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I could run the sql plus and use the spool tool.

```
sqlplus usr/pass
```

Now with SqlPlus I can just use the regular spool command.

Thanks all who helped.